# Deployed Timer Job not taking new code when deployed

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, deployment, timer-jobs

I've realized recently that, when re-deploying (either manually or through vs2010) my timer job feature package, the updated execute code is not being deployed.  Strange yea. Essentially, I'll deactivate all features,retract my package, change the exec code in vs2010, re-deploy, and the code won't be updated. The old timer code will run.

I found a fix though. If I change the assembly and file versions with each deployment, the changes get picked up. Anyone know why this is necessary?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to restart the SharePoint timer service (Start > Run > Services.msc). The timer jobs code get cached in the timer.

Comment: Right on! Thanks.
I added the commands to the lab/production deployment scripts.
Also, in VS2010, I added 

    net stop sptimerv4
    net start sptimerv4

to the "Post Deployment Command Line Field" in Project -> Properties -> SharePoint.

Comment: Good idea on adding it to the deploy process in VS.

Comment: The same applies to WSS/MOSS 2007. Forgot about restarting the timer service, thanks StackExchange!

Answer (score 11):

Just try to run this from the run dialogue

1. net stop sptimerv4
2. net start sptimerv4

this should do the trick.

Comment: Or from PowerShell `Restart-Service SPTimerV4`

Comment: @PerJakobsen You should add this as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change your assembly and file version numbers:
Project Properties -> Application -> Assembly Information...

Comment: Whoo, no, that should not be necessary to make it pick up your new code.

Comment: a solution, not 'the solution'.